# Como pegar apenas o mês da data com PHP do banco de dados

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, data

Bem a data esta no formato ( 2020-02-10 17:04:01 )
Então quero apenas pegar o mês ou dia separadamente, os dados estao salvos no danco de dados, consigo pegar toda a data, mas queria pegar separadamente apenas o dia e mes.
**Aqui um trecho do codigo:**

```
$query  = "SELECT * FROM barraswiki ORDER BY aprovam DESC, reg_data DESC"; 
$data = mysqli_query($dbc, $query);  
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($data)){
$date = new DataTime($row['reg_data']);
$mes = data($date, 'd');
// code......
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Bastaria fazer isso no SQL, no caso:

```
SELECT MONTH(reg_data) as mes, DAY(reg_data) as dia, barraswiki.* from barraswiki order by aprovam DESC, reg_data DESC;
```

Mas também pode formatar datas assim:

`SELECT DATE_FORMAT(reg_data,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_brasil ...`

Para pegar o registro no PHP pega o alias:

```
$mes = $row['mes'];
$dia = $row['dia'];
```

Comment: Obrigado amigo, porém ocorreu um errou ali no SELECT, o nome da tabela é barraswiki. Então como faço para pegar os dados da tabela? ali acima você colocou ( *.barraswiki ), no entanto deu erro. Poderia corrigir amigo, desde já agradço.

Comment: Tava invertido, foi mal! >D

Comment: Caramba, rodou perfeito :) Você não faz ideia de como você me ajudou, estava estudando bastante date no PHP, e aprendi muito, mas sua ajuda me mostrou que era no SQL que eu devia ter focado. Valeu mesmo pela ajuda! Fica com Deus.

Answer (score 6):

Caso queira trazer apenas um campo específico de um registro de data, você pode usar **funções de data** como DAY e MONTH, como [explicado aqui](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-date-functions/).

**Exemplo**

```
SELECT MONTH(coluna_data) FROM suaTabela; /*seleciona apenas o mês*/
```

Para sua tabela, o SELECT ficaria assim:

```
SELECT MONTH(reg_data), DAY(reg_data) from barraswiki order by aprovam DESC, reg_data DESC;
```

Já para selecionar apenas um campo de uma váriavel de data no PHP, você pode usar a função *date()*, como explicado [aqui](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php).

**Exemplo**

```
echo date('m',$variavelDeData); //Representação numérica de um mês, com zero à esquerda
```

Comment: O amigo ali acima já me ajudou, mas graças a você tenho outra forma bem simples de usar, obrigado amigo! Valeu pela força.

Answer (score -3):

Tenho uma tabela div_parcelamentos com o campo `div_data` em formato `date()`
obtive a data via query `$vencto  =$row['div_vencimento'];`

Como a data está em formato americano `"2022-03-??"` utilizei o comando abaixo:

```
$dia=substr($vencto,8,2) - obtenha dois caracteres à partir da posição 8
$mes=substr($vencto,5,2) - obtenha dois caracteres à partir da posição 5
$ano=substr($vencto,0,4) - obtenha quatro caracteres à partir do início
```

Como precisei fazer um loop no mês e, consequentemente verificar a mudança de ano procedi conforme abaixo:

```
$mes=$mes+1;  somei mais um mês à variável
if ($mes>12) { 
   $mes=1; $ano++; }
   $parcinic++;
   $vencim=$ano."/".substr(100+$mes,1,2)."/".$dia;
```

Como o PHP é inteligente e já identifica o tipo de campo, a sintaxe acima foi suficiente para ele mudar a data.